# Django blog send an email to administrator when users submit a form

Tags: python, django, forms, sendmail

### Background

I am building a blog about my research group. There is a join_us page where users are able to fill a application form to apply for the research program. The basic function works well but I want to notify my mentor when someone submits the application.

### Problem

The official document of Django about the sending_email is a bit ambiguous and I still do not figure out how to add the value of the form into the email content.

### Code

`views.py`

```
def application_action(request):
    last_name = request.POST.get('last_name', 'LAST_NAME')
    first_name = request.POST.get('first_name', 'FIRST_NAME')
    email_address = request.POST.get('email_address', 'EMAIL_ADDRESS')
    program_type = request.POST.get('program_type', 'PROGRAM_TYPE')
    personal_statement = request.POST.get('personal_statement', 'PERSONAL_STATEMENT')
    resume = request.FILES.get('resume')
    models.Application.objects.create(last_name=last_name, first_name=first_name, program_type=program_type,
                                    email_address=email_address, personal_statement=personal_statement,
                                  resume=resume)
    send_mail(
    'An new application',
    'Dear professor, you received an new application. Please check it out in the administration console',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
    application = models.Application.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'research_spacecoupe/join_us.html', {'application': application})
```

`settings.py:`

```
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
    EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.126.com'
    EMAIL_PORT = 25
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'demo@126.com'
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'demo'
    DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'demo <demo@126.com>'
```

`models.py`

```
class Application(models.Model):
    program_choice = (('硕士项目', '硕士'), ('博士项目', '博士'), ('博士后项目', '博士后'))
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="名")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="姓")
    email_address = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    program_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=program_choice)
    personal_statement = models.TextField(null=True)
    application_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=1)
    resume = models.FileField(upload_to='resumes')

def application_info(self):
    return '%s %s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name, self.program_type)
```

### Note

I wish the value of the form in the HTML can be sent with the mail so that the administrator can view more information.

Comment: The current code is working fine ? or not?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki, it works so far. And I have known how to add value to the email content. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format the email to send the details. You can add more details as per your requirement. Below is an example.

```
models.Application.objects.create(last_name=last_name, first_name=first_name, program_type=program_type,
                                    email_address=email_address, personal_statement=personal_statement,
                                  resume=resume)
    send_mail(
    'An new application',
    'Dear professor, you received an new application. Please check it out in the administration console details are as follows' +
    ': first_name: {}, last_name: {}'.format(first_name, last_name),
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

Comment: Hello, friend. I want to add a simple function: raise a toast alert to remind users that the application has been submitted successfully. How to do that?

Comment: You can ask another question for this. Since its completely a different one so ask another question. I'll be happy to help you there